# Is there a way to ignore the retry call from Azure B2C on timeout for api connector?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c, dynamics-365

When a user sign-up, it calls a C# azure function (api connector). Then the azure function needs to create the user and other stuffs into Dynamics 365 since we want a perfect sync from B2C to Dynamics 365.

However, I almost always timeout (20 seconds) since the time for spinning the function + time for creating all accounts/contacts/etc.. in Dynamics is most of the time more than 20 seconds (thanks for Dynamics, mostly, taking a lot of time for create request (up to 15 seconds for creating an account!!!)). At the timeout, B2C sends a new request to my azure function, which then create a duplicate of everything that has already been created. I don't want to because it will fill the environment with a lot of duplicate stuff.

One solution was to use a message bus or something like that to pill up the requests, however we don't fancy this solution since we want to make sure all the things are created in Dynamics 365 before completing the B2C signup (in case of error or whatever, since B2C REALLY needs to be in sync with Dynamics) and because we return a custom attribute to B2C for future use.

I would like to know if there is a way to do what I want? I would be perfect if I could only increase the timeout, but I saw that I can't do that...

Comment: Do you think keeping the function warmed up all the time would decrease the overall time to a level within the timout threshold?

Comment: It would not help since the major bottleneck are the calls to dynamics. However, By using some caching service, I'm able to control and to know which is the original request and which is only a retry. With that, I can sync both states and have 40 seconds to do everything instead of 20 seconds. It's the best solution we were able to come with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot increase the API connector timeout in AAD B2C.